# How can I join a QT GUI to a non-C++ main program?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, mono, rust

QT appears to be the best cross-platform GUI toolkit available. Unfortunately, it is in C++, and bindings for it to many interesting languages (such as D, Rust, Julia, and Mono on *nix) are either not available or not maintained. GTK bindings are usually available, but GTK looks ugly on Windows and (especially) OS X. wxWidgets bindings would also be nice, but are not available or are unmaintained for D, Rust, and Julia (For Julia, I could go through Python for both toolkits, but that is slow and clumsy).

How can I bind my C++ GUI to an non-C++ main program?

Comment: Wrap your Qt routines as C functions; most language implementations accept C external functions. What exact language are you thinking of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a handful of options here.

First of all, you can bind your GUI and your main app via C API. GUIs are usually done via callbacks which are invoked through an event loop, so you will have to expose functions in your high-level language as C callbacks in order for them to be called from the event loop. Then you will need to start Qt event loop. There are multiple ways to do it depending on which language you use. For example, if you use Rust, you can make a static or dynamic library and link your C++ GUI program to it. In this case the "entry point" of your program will be the C++ part. If you use something like Julia, you will probably want to compile the C++ part as a library which would also expose a function which calls Qt event loop. So in this case the "entry point" will be your higher-level part which still would need to call back into the C++ library.

The second approach is closer to web UIs. You can make your GUI a client for your main app written in another language. They can exchange messages through some existing protocol, like HTTP, or you can implement your own protocol over a low-level TCP or UDP connection, or you can use "middle-level" messaging library like [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) or [nanomsg](http://nanomsg.org/). You can also consider dropping Qt altogether and just write a web app, with your program as a web server. This is the most cross-platform way to write a GUI now, I guess :)

Comment: Would the second approach be the best if I wanted to consider the UI as a modular component that might be rewritten later (such as for native look and feel)?

Comment: @Demetri, I believe yes, since it will be more decoupled than direct C bindings.

Comment: So with all these options, what are the speed differences (in terms of passing data from GUI to the backend, backend processing to passing results back to GUI for rendering) when:

1. GUI and Backend in same language (say Qt and C++)
2. GUI and Backend in different language (say C++ Qt/Julia)
3. Webapp where GUI rendered in browser, with program as server

What would be a good way to profile these options?

Comment: @Asy your question is way too complex to answer it in a comment, and updating the answer would be incorrect because it is not related to the original question. Therefore, you should create a separate question.